# Symfony approach to displaying aggregate entity data

Tags: symfony, aggregate-functions

I have 3 entities `Expertise, Person and Tag,`  related through a join entity, `AssociatedTag` which has a composite primary key (expertise_id, tag_id, person_id). This works correctly.

Because more than one Person can add the same Tag to a particular Expertise, simply displaying each tag string can result in duplicates.  If I weren't working in Symfony, I'd just do an aggregate query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    t.tag, a.tag_id
    a.expertise_id,
    COUNT(a.person_id) AS tagcount,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.person_id = ? THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS has_curuser
FROM
    expertise_tags a
        JOIN
    tag t ON (a.tag_id = t.id)
WHERE
    a.expertise_id = ?   #397
GROUP BY t.tag , a.expertise_id;
```

which would produce data like this:

```
foobe   9   397 1   0
neato   7   397 2   1
pita    8   397 1   0
```

and then output with a simple loop and conditions like `has_curuser == TRUE` and `tagcount > 1` to control the output options.

I get the  impression with Symfony, that there ought to be a class for holding the aggregate results or perhaps there should be a data transformer or Twig extension that takes unaggregated results and aggregates them (though that seems inefficient).

What is the correct Symfony approach to this situation?

Comment: Little misunderstood the question, the problem is to perform a query, or output the result?

Comment: @forgottenbas: If it is correct to do the query, where should it go (perhaps the controller?) and how to do it; if it is not correct to do the query, how to output the `AssociatedTag` collection so that the aggregate characteristics can be taken into account.

Comment: One possible solution is to use native queries. I describe it in my answer. Yes, you can run query in controller, or in entity repository or from custom service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that the doctrine DQL supports a limited part of the functionality of the native SQL language for complex queries, you can use [native queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

> With NativeQuery you can execute native SELECT SQL statements and map
>   the results to Doctrine entities or any other result format supported
>   by Doctrine.